# Facebook marketing API insights doesn't return data for all days within the range

Tags: facebook

I am trying to use the Insights API to get daily performance stats on my ad account. To achieve this I am setting the `time_increment=1`. I expect to receive stats for every day within the interval specified, even if there is no data for those days (in this case counts would be zero). Instead I get stats only for one day, presumably one day when my test account was active.

Here is the call:

```
curl "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.7/act_[redacted]/insights?
fields=clicks,impressions,cpc,ctr&access_token=
[redacted]&time_range%5Bsince%5D=2016-09-01
&time_range%5Buntil%5D=2016-09-09&time_increment=1"
```

Output:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "clicks": "3",
      "impressions": "89",
      "cpc": 0.29333333333333,
      "ctr": 3.3707865168539,
      "date_start": "2016-09-06",
      "date_stop": "2016-09-06"
   }
  ],
 "paging": {
    "cursors": {
    "before": "MAZDZD",
    "after": "MAZDZD"
 }
}
}
```

Notice that my time range is set to `2016-09-01 - 2016-09-09`, but I've got data only for the day of `2016-09-06`.

The question is: Is it possible to get a response, similar to the one above, but with an entry for every day within the time range, even if some of the entries will have no data (i.e. counts will be zero or null)?

Comment: I've had a similar problem. i want insights on a certain date range but it disregards my date range or atleast in the returned insights, the start and end dates are wrong..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We've reached out to Facebook, and they have said that indeed for the time periods where there is no data, no insights objects will be returned. It is up to caller to fill in the blanks if they want to build a time series dataset.